# how can I update views with subquery (select statement)?

Tags: sql-server, view

Here is an example of view A:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason |
| 2 | Smith |
| 3 | Jenny |
| 4 | Tom |

I am using a `SELECT` statement, which is the expected result. The result comes from three tables by using an `INNER JOIN`.

Select:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jason |
| 2 | Smith |

Simply put, I want to update the view with the result of the `SELECT` statement.

I ran `DELETE` with `NOT EXISTS` and a subquery, but I am getting an error below:

```sql
DELETE FROM [A]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> View or function 'TEST.dbo.testView' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

How can I get the sorted data by updating the view with subquery..? I am expecting some query like:

```sql
UPDATE [A]
SET [A].[dbo].[ID] = (SELECT ....)
```

Another confusion: even though I update the records, still non-selected records will exist. That's why I tried to use `DELETE` instead of `UPDATE`. But I cannot delete the view records due to the error I mentioned.

Please anyone help me out.

Comment: What is the definition of the `VIEW`? The error is telling you the problem here, so if you *must* run DML statements against the `VIEW` you will likely need to use `INSTEAD OF` `TRIGGER`s.

Comment: You can't update views except in certain circumstances (no joins being the primary one). If you show us the three table definitions plus the view definition we can see.

Comment: Dude, if you anonymize your code a little further, there will be an empty question left. How about specifying the actual code you're trying to run, and perhaps the view definition as well

Comment: SQL Server in general doesn't support deleting from multiple tables. What you can do is to help it on the way, something like this: delete t from (select col1FromTableA, col2FromTableA FROM View) t WHERE someCondition = 1. So, the idea is that you select only columns from one table, this way the server knows what you're trying to delete. It doesn't always work but it could in your case